# Adding Inline-block moving other items below in react bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap

I have been using navbar from react bootstrap.

Inside the `navbar-link` item I need to add an image followed by a seprator rectangle.

For this I added a div followed by image inside `nav-bar` link.

For them to be on same line I made seperator display property to be `inline-block`. When I do that image left side of this div is moving down a bit.

What is happening ?
[image]

```
inside navbar:
<Nav.Link href="#UNKNOWN">
        <img
        src="assets/group-6.png"
        alt="unkown">
        </img>
        <div className = "seperator">
        </div>
    </Nav.Link> 
css: 

.seperator{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
  height: 38px;
  border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
}
```

How to make image and separator div tag vertically aligned center?. Do we need to add parent container ?

Comment: There is nothing specific about React in this question. This is a html/css problem. I would suggest you to inspect the elements in chrome dev-tools and see what property is pushing the image down? Also, try using `display:flex; flex-direction: row` on the container element(Nav.Link) instead of using `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this `CSS`.

```
.nav-link{
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
}

.nav-link img{
    align-self: center;
}

.nav-link .seperator{
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 38px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
}
```